# Pandas - How to exclude blank cells when returning a row

Tags: python, pandas, search, null, xlsx

I have just started to use python and pandas and would like to search a dataframe and return a row based on drug name, returning all the column cells which are not blank.

I have this:

```
import pandas as pd
safety = pd.read_excel("safety.xlsx")
searchterm = input("Enter drug name...")
print (safety.loc[safety['Drug_name'] == searchterm])
```

This will return the drug and all columns even the blank ones.

For example each row is a drug and each column is a criteria, each drug could have info for some criteria but not all.

How can I print the drugs row, excluding the blank column cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain a filter on the row:

```
print(safety.loc[safety['Drug_name'] == searchterm][lambda x: x != ''])
```

Or if you only need to drop NA, use `dropna`:

```
print(safety.loc[safety['Drug_name'] == searchterm].dropna())
```

Use a chained filter you can also remove both empty string and NA:

```
print(safety.loc[safety['Drug_name'] == searchterm][lambda x: (x != '') & x.notnull()])
```